# Scaling SignalR With Windows Server Service Bus

Tags: signalr

Is it possible to scale out SignalR using Windows Server Service Bus?

I found sample of doing it with Redis, and I know there are libraries in GitHub for SQL Server (although I couldn't find a working sample for that), but I would like to implement it using the new on-premises Service Bus.

Any ideas / references?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In theory yes. The current stable versions support the Azure Service Bus, the [latest source](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/tree/master/src/Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.ServiceBus) includes a rework of the scaleout providers such that even if it doesn't work out of the box (as the two service bus solutions are designed to have API parity) it should be straightforward to implement.

The service bus scaleout is enabled using its [DependencyResolverExtensions class](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/blob/master/src/Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.ServiceBus/DependencyResolverExtensions.cs).

Comment: Thanks!
I tried to find a sample / tutorial for implementing the provider, but didn't succeed.
Do you know where can I find it?

Comment: Not in theory, there's a package on nuget since the alpha https://nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.ServiceBus/

Comment: @dfowler thanks for the clarification, I tried looking through the wiki and source but couldn't see for sure. I did remember someone posting something about Windows Server Service Bus though.

Comment: If you want to use service bus server then you need to use the UseServiceBus overload and pass all of the required arguments.

Comment: @dfowler even now, months later, the github page says "Scaleout is still in preview and is NOT recommended for production use"... So I'm a but confused

Comment: That's fair. Things change and the project timeline changes as well. Scaleout is actively being worked on with a beta in a few weeks and RTW by end of April.